# Does Amanda or Zmanda support copying backups to RDX?

Tags: linux, backup

I have been using Bacula as my backup solution for my network, which consists of Linux servers, Linux clients, Windows 7 clients and a NAS (via CIFS).

Setting up Bacula to do the backups was not easy.  Now I want to copy these backups to RDX cartridges for off-site archival & storage.  If I thought getting Bacula set up to do the basic backups was hard, getting it set up to copy these backups to RDX is that much harder.  Hard enough in fact that I'm considering abandoning Bacula altogether and going with another product.

We don't have thousands of dollars to spend on a backup appliance (we're a startup), but I still feel that proper backups are absolutely critical; so I'm looking at open source packages.

The backup server is Ubuntu 12.04.  I know that (A|Z)manda supports archival to tape devices, but I wasn't able to find any information about archiving to RDX.

1. Does Amanda/Zmanda support copying backups to RDX for off-site storage?
2. How difficult is getting this set up?